Two people on ice floor
If person A is pushing person B, then A experiences a force coming from B by Newton's third law. This means that B is doing working on A. However, according to my intuition, A feels tired while B doesn't because A is actively exerting force, while B is passively exerting force.
My question is, Does the fact that B doesn't actively exerting force means that he doesn't consume energy? If he doesn't consume energy, how can he do work on A which causes A's increasing in kinetic energy?

You think of work as exhaustion. That is a mistake. If you throw a stone over the ice so it hits a stationary stone, does the moving stone then become "exhausted" at impact? That is not meaningful.
This concept of tiredness after an effort has been done is purely a human condition (or, should I say, purely a condition of biological organisms). That is due to the manner in which our bodies produce muscle force. But there are many other ways to produce force.

Force from muscles comes from rapid or controlled extension and contraction of muscle fibers. That process requires biological effort that gives a sensation of exhaustion of your body. Internal chemical energy such as from nutrition is spent on this production of a force.

Force from a rocket engine is produced by the controlled consumption/burning of fuel. At some point the fuel is out and the force will end. So, internal chemical energy in the form of fuel is spent.

But force from a stone hitting another stone has got no complex production requirements behind it. No internal energy is spent to produce this force. The work it does solely comes from its carried kinetic energy.


So, the concept of exhaustion when a force is exerted or work is done is clearly a special-case for biological bodies, and not something that will happen generally.  But all of this doesn't matter. Because when we talk about work in a physical sense, then we are refering to the work done by the force, not the work that it took to produce its force. Your bodily muscle contractions and cell movements etc. were all internal and was not exerted on the other person - only the resulting force was exerted on the other person. It is only the work done by this final force that the other person absorbs - all the work your body did to produce the force did not influence the other person at all.
In summary, you get more exhausted when you push off from another person on the ice than that other person does because your pushing force is produced via much more complex processes than his reaction force is. But all that is not relevant when considering what the consequence of the produced force is. It turns out via Newton's 3rd law, as you rightly say, that the forces are equal in magnitude and thus that the work done by each force is the same. Maybe not the work done to produce the forces, but the work done by the forces.

I think my problem is that there is no point in saying B consumes energy, because energy in physic is just a quantity calculated with some formula. Energy in physic doesn't belong to a body neither can it be consumed

@tgwxsjdWXS "Consuming energy" in a physical context might simply refer to ebergy being transfered to or absorbed by the object. In your setup with two bodies on ice, then both bodies do work on each other, hence both bodies absorb this energy. This work is then manifested as kinetic energy, but jn other contexts it could have been converted into yet other types of, maybe internal, energies.

It's a good question, and the answer is that while we tend to say "A does work on B" or "B does work on A" this isn't strictly correct. We should be saying:

The force acting between A and B does work

Then there is a separate question where the energy for that work comes from.
For example suppose there is a compressed spring between A and B and that creates a force between them. Both A and B get accelerated by the spring but neither feel tired because it's the energy stored in the compressed spring that supplies the work. Now use A's arm as the spring and it's the energy from the muscles in A's arm that does the work. As it happens the energy in A's arm came originally from A, so as you say A feels tired, but my point is it's not really a matter of "A does work on B" or "B does work on A" but rather it's the force generated by A's arm doing work on both A and B.

B never moved, and thus there is no such thing as work being done on B, at least in the Earth-Wall frame of reference. But of course, everything else is perfectly correct.

@naturallyInconsistent A and B are both on ice so both slide when A (A's arm!) pushes B.

Oops, sorry, I was converting to the Wall-A case in my mind while replying to yours. My bad.

Nice model. What if I view A and the spring in your case as A? Then B would do work on A, shouldn't B consume energy? maybe there is some hidden logic error in the statement: if B does work on A, then B must consume energy?

@tgwxsjdWXS Again you're saying "B does work on A" when really you should say "the force between B and A does work on A". The point is that it isn't B doing the work so B doesn't get tired. It's A's arm doing the work, and you have a difference between A and B because A's arm is attached to A not B and that creates the asymmetry,

Generally, your model is good as it is very intuitive and explains what's happening. But you cannot say that my model is wrong as what this model predicts is not what's happening in reality. What I want to know is, what's the underlying problem in my model(view A's body and arm as a whole, and force from B times the traveld distance of center of mass of A is the work done by B)?

Let us replace person B with a wall. It is clear that the wall will NEVER feel tired, and it also would not be moving, and so the wall cannot be doing work. Yet, person A can push himself off the wall, doing work on himself and increase his own kinetic energy.
There is really not much of a conflict. You just have to be careful in considering all the physics involved, and the solution will present itself. Just because person B is playing the role of a wall, maybe going to be pushed away by person A as opposed to the unmovable wall, does not really change the physics concepts at play by too much.

How can A do work on himself if I view A as a whole and the external force comes from the wall?

In your assumption, the wall has no change in momentum but A has change in momentum. And there is no external force applied to the system consisting of A and the wall. It would contradict the conversation of momentum

There is no difficulty. The Earth has to hold the wall stationary, and so the Earth will be supplying the momentum for the wall-A system. But you should be focusing on the wall pushing on A and thus supplying A with the momentum that A finally acquires. The energy for this motion comes from A himself, converted from chemical potential energy of the muscles into the kinetic energy of A.

The force comes from the wall. Doesn't the wall do work on A? How can the energy consumption happen in A only?

The wall is clearly not moving. Its $\vec F\cdot\vec{\mathrm dx}$ is clearly zero because $\vec{\mathrm dx}=\vec0$. It is not just obvious that the conclusion must then be that A is providing the work required to move himself, but that it is also precisely what you would have expected without any mathematics.

But A is moving right? force from wall exerted on A times the distance A has traveled(when A stretched his arms his center of gravity is moving) is non zero. Thus the wall has done work on A.

The centre of mass of A is moving, but the reason it is moving is because A is extending his arms. The immovable wall cannot do work on anything; A performed energy conversion on himself, converting chemical potential energy into kinetic energy, which is the only allowed step available. This is only allowed because the wall provided the momentum necessary for this conversion process. Your worldview as it is cannot fully capture the correct physics if you keep insisting upon it.


If he doesn't consume energy, how can he do work on A which causes A's
increasing in kinetic energy?

As @naturallyinconsistent has already correctly pointed out, A doesn’t acquire its kinetic energy from work done by B.  It acquires it from internal work done by one part of A’s body (primarily the muscles of the shoulders and arms) on the rest of the body, the energy coming from the conversion of chemical potential energy in the part of the body doing the internal work. The role of the equal and opposite force that B applies to A is to conserve the momentum of the A-B system (ignoring any kinetic friction between the skaters and the ice there is no net external force acting on the A-B system).
Consider the following non biological analogy slightly different than that described in @John Rennie answer.
Replace A and B each with a mass connected to an ideal initially compressed spring each with some sort of latching mechanism. The spring portions of A and B are initially in contact with each other.
A’s spring-mass becomes unlatched allowing its spring to expand and exert a force on B while B’s spring-mass remains latched. A does work on B transferring energy to B giving it kinetic energy (the amount depending on the mass of B and Newton’s second law.) Although the equal and opposite force B exerts on A assures conservation of momentum of the A-B system, B transfers no energy to A as B’s spring remains compressed.
Bottom line: all of the kinetic energy acquired by the A-B system comes from the elastic potential energy initially stored A’s spring. For the skaters the energy comes from the conversion of chemical potential energy initially stored in A’s muscles.
Hope this helps.

The concept of work and energy in physics has very little to do with feeling tired, and you should try to keep the two concepts entirely separate.
If you stand still for a long time you will feel tired, even though you are doing no work as the concept is used in physics. But if you lie down for a long time you do not feel tired. This is a matter of physiology, not physics.
On the other hand, a plank of wood never feels tired, no matter whether it is standing upright or lying on the ground. Even if it is doing work in physics terms - for example, it is being used as a springboard - it will never feel tired.
